# Inserting %20 in a string character clarification

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, in-place

Hi I am doing a Cracking the Coding I have coded up a solution, by reading the answer explained in plain english, however I do not understand one line of code.

**The Question**

Replace all white space with "%20", empty spaces have been added at the end of the text to accomodate for the new symbols

Input : "Mr John Smith   ", 13
Output : Mr%20John%20Smith

**My Solution**

```
*static void replaceSpaces(char[] arr,int trueLength)
{
   int spaces = 0;
   int newLength = 0;
   int length = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<trueLength; ++i)
   {
       if(arr[i] == ' ')
       {
           ++spaces;
       }
       newLength = trueLength +spaces*2; // We already have one space, so we need to add 2 extra spaces to fit the %20 symbol
   }
    for(int i = trueLength-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(arr[i] == ' ')
        {
            arr[newLength-1] = '0';
            arr[newLength-2] = '2';
            arr[newLength-3] = '%';
            newLength = newLength - 3;    

        }
        else
        {
            arr[newLength-1] = arr[i];
            newLength = newLength - 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arr);
}*
```

I dont understand why we need this line of code (**newLength = newLength - 3**), I think we need it because after we remove space with the symbol, we subtract 3 to go to the next empty space, is this correct?

Comment: This code doesn't do all that you want:
- it doesn't remove the spaces in the end

Comment: For performance: you can place the assignment `newLength = trueLength +spaces*2;` outside the for-loop (can be done once).

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, if you mean: to the next empty space to write a new character.
The codeline `newLength = newLength - 3;` exists because you need to skip 3 characters ('0', '2' and '%'). Else you would overwrite them.

I must mention that your code is quite typical since you are filling the array backwards.